# perl cpan module installation

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I have a server where I've installed some perl modules.  I installed the first few via CPAN, i.e. perl -MCPAN -e 'install Module::Name' as a non-root user.

Then I ran into some issues, and just started installing them via sudo or root.

I found out last night via some output from a cron job, that some of the scripts are failing because they can't locate the modules in the @INC array.

I discovered that on the server in question, perl -V shows the following:

as root:

```
%ENV:
  PERL5LIB="/root/perl5/lib/perl5:"
  PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=":/root/perl5"
  PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /root/perl5"
  PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/root/perl5"
@INC:
  /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
  /root/perl5/lib/perl5
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  /usr/local/share/perl5
  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/lib64/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
```

and as a non-root user:

```
%ENV:
  PERL5LIB="/home/user/perl5/lib/perl5:"
  PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=":/home/user/perl5"
  PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /home/user/perl5"
  PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/user/perl5"
@INC:
  /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
  /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  /usr/local/share/perl5
  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/lib64/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
```

I checked another server, where installation of perl modules has never had a problem, and it shows the same output whether run as a non-root user or root, and only has @INC, no $ENV defined.

```
@INC:
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  /usr/local/share/perl5
  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/lib64/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
```

So my question is, How can I configure CPAN on the server I'm having problems to not have different Environments and @INC values for different users.  I'd rather it just have one default system location for perl modules that are accessible by all.  I assume I need to run o conf init from the CPAN shell, or edit /root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm and /home/user/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig directly, but not too sure what exact edits I need to make.

Thank you,

Comment: Most of @INC is hardcoded into Perl when it was built. Env var like PERL5LIB are added to it. `cpan` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where they are installed, since the path into which they will be installed will be in `@INC` (unless you explicitly override this).

Comment: Note that you appear to be using the system Perl. You should your system's package manager to add packages to that, not `cpan`. There may be risks to doing otherwise.

Comment: No, as I stated above, some of the modules are in /home/user and some are in /root, there are different @INC, so the ones in /root aren't being discovered when run from cron.  Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: To reiterate ikegami's point.  If you don't like the results of your current environment variables, they are easy enough to change/remove.

Comment: ok, some examples please, that would also work for the scripts being called via cron?

Answer (score 0):

Since cron tasks could be defined as "system" related I'd do as @ikegami suggests and stick with the system perl and use the package manager to keep the environment consistent across users. It's best to keep **root** and `/root` out of the picture: if **root** is installing to their $HOME you might as well just use system packages.

If you are creating custom scripts for `cron` and running them as a user then you can create a consistent perl environment (or several) for that user with [`perlbrew`](http://perlbrew.pl), [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) (which you seem to already have installed) and [`cpanminus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) (which can be installed alongside and work seamlessly with `perlbrew`).

As a quick fix you can extend your `@INC` with `-I` (but a non-root user is not going to be able to access `/root` obviously) and your `%ENV` with other switches and environment variables. See [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for some of those - *e.g.*:

- `-Idirectory`

  Directories specified by -I are prepended to the search path for modules (`@INC`).

Comment: Again, gonna need more specific instructions if the information you supplied is going to be of value.

Comment: `-I` doesn't add arch dirs, IIRC. Better off using `PERL5LIB=... script` or `perl -Mlib=... script`

Comment: @ikegami - you are right of course.  I neglected to consider `XS` extensions and the like. Even more reasons to stick with vendor packages.